# PHP mysql check on equal dates -> one variable

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have two tables:

- Table one with events on a certain date
- Table two with the same events but with multiple available hours to register on the same date or event

The problem is that some events occur multiple times on one date. I want the events from the same date to be merged under one date without making a third table.

Is this possible?

This is my code to display all the dates from table one without connecting to table two:

```
$result = $conn->query
   ("SELECT * FROM Table01 ORDER BY datum ASC") //rand()
    or die($mysqli->error);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): 

      $update = $row['datum'];
      $createDate = new DateTime($update);
      $strip = $createDate->format('d-m-Y'); 
      echo $strip;

endwhile;
```

Output is for example:

- 28-01-2017 (9 A.M., 10 A.M.)
- 28-01-2017 (11 A.M.)
- 29-01-2017 (6 A.M., 8 A.M.)

And I want it to be:

- 28-01-2017 (9 A.M., 10 A.M., 11 A.M.)
- 29-01-2017 (6 A.M., 8 A.M.)

Comment: Haven't seen `while` written like that in *a while*.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: did you try group by?

Comment: Are you getting the time output  from the given code?

Comment: I get the time from the second table.
I work with two pages, the first with the dates that are clickable to page two (with the available hours for the specific date).

Comment: BTW, is it wrong to use: 
While():
Instead of
While () {}

Comment: No as long as you use `endwhile;` with a `while():`

Comment: I fail to see how that code produces that output

Comment: If you show us all the code, maybe we can help. But this is of no help whatsoever and obviously not what you are actually running

Comment: And somehow it gets 3 upvotes. Great upvote a good question. But not one like this